# Location data from the firebase not loading into the google map

Tags: firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

the map is not loading the latitude and longitude from the firebase

```
@Override
         public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap=googleMap;
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mUsers.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Post2 post2= snapshot.getValue(Post2.class);
                LatLng location = new LatLng(post2.latitude,post2.longtitude);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(post2.placename)).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

The results are to retire the longitude and latitude  from the firebase

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? you mean lat lng are not displaying the map ?

Comment: yes. it's not retiriving the  lat and lng from firebase

Comment: debug the code using breakpoints to make sure you are actually getting lat lng from firebase or not